# rstan MCMC: Different squence of data resulting in different results, why?

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, stan, rstan

I am new to Stan and rstan.

I recently may find a weird **issue** when I worked on Markov chain Monte Carlo (**MCMC**). In short, *for example*, the data has 10 observations, say ID 1 to 10. Now, I permutate it by shifting the 10th row between the original first and second rows, say ID 1, 10, and 2 to 9. Two different scenarios of data will give different estimates, even I fix the same random seed.

To illustrate the issue in a simpler way, I write the following R scripts.

```
##TEST 01
# generate data
N <- 100
set.seed(123)
Y <- rnorm(N, 1.6, 0.2)

stan_code1 <- "
data {
  int <lower=0> N;        //number of data
  real Y[N];              //data in an (C++) array
}

parameters {
  real mu;                //mean parameter of a normal distribution
  real <lower=0> sigma;   //standard deviation parameter of a normal distribution
}

model {
  //prior distributions for parameters
  mu ~ normal(1.7, 0.3);
  sigma ~ cauchy(0, 1);
  
  //likelihood of Y given parameters
  for (i in 1:N) {
    Y[i] ~ normal(mu, sigma);
  }
}
"

# compile model
library(rstan)
model1 <- stan_model(model_code = stan_code1) #usually, take half a minute to run

# pass data to stan and run model
set.seed(123)
fit <- sampling(model1, list(N=N, Y=Y), iter=200, chains=4)
print(fit)
#         mean se_mean   sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%  97.5% n_eff Rhat
# mu      1.62    0.00 0.02   1.58   1.61   1.62   1.63   1.66   473 1.00
# sigma   0.18    0.00 0.01   0.16   0.18   0.18   0.19   0.21   141 1.02
# lp__  117.84    0.07 0.85 115.77 117.37 118.07 118.51 118.78   169 1.01


Yp <- Y[c(1,100,2:99)]
set.seed(123)
fit2 <- sampling(model1, list(N=N, Y=Yp), iter=200, chains=4)
print(fit2)
#         mean se_mean   sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%  97.5% n_eff Rhat
# mu      1.62    0.00 0.02   1.59   1.61   1.62   1.63   1.66   480 0.99
# sigma   0.18    0.00 0.01   0.16   0.18   0.18   0.19   0.21   139 1.02
# lp__  117.79    0.09 0.95 115.72 117.35 118.05 118.49 118.77   124 1.01
```

As we can see from the above simple case, two results *fit* and *fit2* are **different**.
And, even stranger, if I write the *likelihood* before the *priors* (previousy, the *priors* are written ahead of the *likelihood*) in code file, the same random seed and the same data will still give different estimates.

```
##TEST 01'
# generate data
#N <- 100
set.seed(123)
Y <- rnorm(N, 1.6, 0.2)

stan_code11 <- "
data {
  int <lower=0> N;        //number of data
  real Y[N];              //data in an (C++) array
}

parameters {
  real mu;                //mean parameter of a normal distribution
  real <lower=0> sigma;   //standard deviation parameter of a normal distribution
}

model {
  //likelihood of Y given parameters
  for (i in 1:N) {
    Y[i] ~ normal(mu, sigma);
  }
  
  //prior distributions for parameters
  mu ~ normal(1.7, 0.3);
  sigma ~ cauchy(0, 1);
}
"

# compile model
#library(rstan)
model11 <- stan_model(model_code = stan_code11) #usually, take half a minute to run

# pass data to stan and run model
set.seed(123)
fit11 <- sampling(model11, list(N=N, Y=Y), iter=200, chains=4)
print(fit11)
#         mean se_mean   sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%  97.5% n_eff Rhat
# mu      1.62    0.00 0.02   1.58   1.61   1.62   1.63   1.66   455 0.99
# sigma   0.19    0.00 0.01   0.16   0.18   0.18   0.20   0.21    94 1.04
# lp__  117.68    0.08 0.93 115.24 117.18 117.90 118.45 118.77   149 1.01

##TEST01 was
#         mean se_mean   sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%  97.5% n_eff Rhat
# mu      1.62    0.00 0.02   1.58   1.61   1.62   1.63   1.66   473 1.00
# sigma   0.18    0.00 0.01   0.16   0.18   0.18   0.19   0.21   141 1.02
# lp__  117.84    0.07 0.85 115.77 117.37 118.07 118.51 118.78   169 1.01
```

Answer (score 3):

Stan does not utilize the same pseudo random-number generator as R. Thus, calling `set.seed(123)` only makes `Y` repeatable and does not make the MCMC sampling repeatable. In order to accomplish the later, you need to pass an integer as the `seed` argument to the `stan` (or `sampling`) function in the rstan package like
`sampling(model11, list(N = N, Y = Y), seed = 1234)`.

Even then, I could imagine that permuting the observations could result in different realizations of the draws from the posterior distribution due to floating-point reasons. But none of this really matters (unless you conduct too few iterations or get warning messages) because the posterior distribution is the same even if a finite set of realizations from the posterior distribution are randomly different numbers.